# How to count the rows in a gridview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that is being populated correctly. When the user presses the Search button, the function ShowData() is called which presents the data based on the criteria entered into the textbox. I want to be able to count how many rows are created in the gridview.

I know I can just count it from the SQL Database Table, but I feel simply counting the rows in the gridview would be so much easier! (Please correct me if I'm wrong!)

I've tried to use `search_results = GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();` in code behind in the ShowData() function with this markup:

```
<div class="size_info" id="allSelected" runat="server" visible="false"><br />
                There are <asp:Label ID="search_results" runat="server"></asp:Label> entries for this search criteria.  
</div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't seem to be returning any value (not even 0!).

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: `GridView1.RowCount`

Comment: If you want to do it in code behind, why to count rows from gridview? Why not the DataTable.Rows.Count() when you bind the DataTable with GridView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
search_results = GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
```

will give compilation error as

> System.String cannot be converted to System.Web.UI.Label

Use

```
search_results.Text = GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
```

And make sure that this is written after grid is bound.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled `Pagination`, by using `GridView1.Rows.Count` you will only get the current page rows, so if `PageSize` equals to 10 and you have 60 rows, you will get 10 as result which is not true!

In that case you need to go like this:

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var d = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        if (d != null) lblGridRowsCount.Text = d.Count.ToString();
}
```